# Suppress field based on another field within same rowcolumn - Crystal Reports Crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have a Crystal Reports crosstab with 1 column and 1 row and 3 summary fields. I am trying to suppress the (#2 & #3) sumfields based on the value of the #1 sumfield.

See the screenshot below. I am trying to suppress the fields that say **0 Open** and **0 unSold** if the percentage listed is greater than 10.

Any suggestions would be amazing.

[image: CrossTab Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot of Cross-Tab Expert]

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out. The formula I needed in the Formula Editor Suppression field was:

> GridValueAt(currentRowIndex,CurrentColumnIndex,0) > 10

I hope this solution is clear and useful to others.